# Вывод данных бота в таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть телеграмм бот, в конечном итоге он выводит такую информацию пользователю

```
async def finish_entry(message: types.Message):
    state = dp.current_state(chat=message.chat.id, user=message.from_user.id)
    await state.set_state(None)
    data = await state.get_data()
    sum = data.get('sum')
    address1 = data.get('address1')
    address2 = data.get('address2')
    hash = message.text
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    result_text = '\n'.join(['UserID: ' + str(message.from_user.id), 'Amount: ' + sum, 'User address: ' + address2,'Hash: '+ hash, 'Time: ' + str(time)])
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=finish_text, reply_markup=markup)
    await bot.send_message(send_result_id, text=result_text)
```

Что надо добавить, чтоб информация из result_text присылалась не только в чат бота, но в какую-нибудь таблицу, в exсel или гугл

Answer (score 2):

потребуется

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Google
gscope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gcredentials = 'ваш файл полученный по инструкции.json'
gdocument = 'название таблицы'
```

чтобы бот мог записывать в Таблицу:

```
Настройка интеграции с Google Drive, Google Spreadsheet
1. https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Библиотека – Создать проект
3. Поиск в библиотеке API:
   a. Google Drive – Включить
   b. Создать учётные данные
   c. Какой API вы используете – Google Drive API
   d. Откуда вы будете вызывать API – Веб-Сервер
   e. К каким данным вы будете обращаться – Данные приложения
   f. Используете этот API для App Engine или Compute Engine – Нет
   g. Выбрать тип учётных данных
   h. Роль – Проект – Редактор
   i. Тип ключа – JSON
   j. Продолжить (загрузка ключа в формате JSON)
4. Открыть полученный файл JSON
5. Скопировать значение поля "client_email"
6. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/
7. Создать новую таблицу
8. Настройки доступа
9. Ввести значение из п.5 и предоставить доступ на редактирование
```

Запись в Гугл Таблицу: дата, время, id, переменные

```
# Запись в Google Sheet Bot
def add_to_gsheet(message, data, text):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(gcredentials, gscope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    wks = gc.open(gdocument).sheet1
    # noinspection PyBroadException
    try:
        # убрать если нужно чтобы была реакция при ЛС боту
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
            return
    except Exception:
        pass
    wks.append_row(
        [datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'), 'Имя бота', message.from_user.id, text, '---', data])
```

вызываем например так:

```
add_to_gsheet(message, 'отмена проведения ' + number_check, 'чек')
```

таким образом в Таблицу будет записано следующее

> 06.04.2020 18:25:50   Имя бота 123 чек    --- отмена проведения ММА00031234

пример для записи в Excel:

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime


def xlsx(message):
    time.sleep(3)

    date = datetime.now()
    quantity = message
    doc = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='table.xlsx')
    sheet = doc['test']

    rows = (
        (date, quantity),
    )

    for row in rows:
        sheet.append(row)
    doc.save('table.xlsx')
```

записывается каждый вызов функции, при условии, что файл table.xlsx закрыт в момент вызова функции

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138376/234134