# Обновление файла XLS через питон

Tags: python, xls

У меня есть программа которая получает информацию с некоторого сайта и сохраняет в XLS файл. Но пока файл открыт, программа не может обновить данные и вылетает. Как мне реализовать программу, что бы XLS файл у меня был открыт в Экспеле, а программа фоном обновляла данные.

```
def save_to_xslx(data, name):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Data Sheet')
    i = 0
    for key in data[0]: #creating headler
        ws.write(0, i, key)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Полагаю, что создать некую БД, (sqlite к примеру) из которой excel файл будет брать данные посредством драйвера и добавлять данные скриптом в эту БД. Можно по кнопке сделать обновление в файле excel можно через ontime (если сейчас уже память не изменяет и правильно пишу название функции VBA)

Comment: А как вы это себе представляете. Открыли файл в EXCEL что-то в нем правите. В это время ваша программа что-то туда пишет. Одновременно в EXCEL еще что-то делаете. Бардак, однако. На то и блокируются файлы от возможности одновременной записи. А если очень надо - то одна программа  открывает файл только на чтение, а другая - только на запись. Ну тогда как-то можно еще организовать паралельность обработки. Но EXCEL не имеет функции "только чтение"

Comment: вы можете использовать GoogleSpreadsheet. можете и сами в нём работать и программа будет писать - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1108229/234134 . в GS можно импортировать текущую таблицу excel