# Как найти клетку в google sheets api на python?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

У меня есть база данных в google sheets и мне надо найти клетку, которая совпадает с написанным словом. После этого напротив этой клетки написать ещё что-то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

gscope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gcredentials = 'New_table GSheet-6f900.json'
gdocument = 'New table'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(gcredentials, gscope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open(gdocument).sheet1

# 1
cell = worksheet.find("Dough")
print("Found something at R%sC%s" % (cell.row, cell.col))

# 1.1
amount_re = re.compile(r'(Big|Enormous) dough')
cell = worksheet.find(amount_re)

# 2
cell_list = worksheet.findall("Rug store")

# 2.1
criteria_re = re.compile(r'(Small|Room-tiering) rug')
cell_list = worksheet.findall(criteria_re)
```

- [gspread.readthedocs](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#finding-a-cell)
- [здесь как получить API ключ и пример записи в таблицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138376/389902)

Comment: добавил ссылку на другой ответ как получить API

Comment: А можно как-то перевести столбцы из чисел в буквы?

Comment: поясните подробнее, пожалуйста, не улавливаю суть вашего вопроса

Comment: В таблицах столбцы указаны буквами, а в вашем коде они указываются числами и хотелось бы их перевести в буквы

Comment: если вы про `#1, 1.1, 2, 2.1`, то это комментарий к коду) первый вариант, еще один первый вариант и т.п.