# Сохранить данные, введённые в боте тг, в один excel файл

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, excel

Интересует такой вопрос, может кто сможет помочь. Написал бота для телеграм. Для фирмы. Бот задаёт вопросы сотруднику(например: Заказчик, дата заказа, время в пути и тд). Сотрудник соответственно вводит эти данные. Нужно сделать так, чтобы в конце эти данные автоматически вносились в таблицу excel. Причём данные всех пользователей бота должны вноситься в один excel файл, но например, с пропуском строк либо с датой, чтобы визуально было видно данные,внесённые разными сотрудниками. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Мне кажется, что с Excel не удобно работать в несколько потоков. Я бы те данные сохранял в базе и отдельным скриптом из базы выгружал в excel

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1108229/234134